# Add event to Google Calendar via API in PHP

Tags: google-calendar-api, google-api-php-client

I've installed the Google API via composer and called the function listed [here](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert) but it is throwing an error. Could you help or provide some example to implement "Add Event", "Delete Event", "Update Event".

[image]

Comment: You have to install first Google Client Library before using the code the link you've provided. Follow this [quickstart](https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/php#step_2_install_the_google_client_library).

Comment: when running file from CLI, it provide a google auth link to open in browser and when opening, it is throwing error "
Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: This application must be run on the command line. in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/googlecalendar/quickstart.php:12 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/googlecalendar/quickstart.php on line 12".